# Adding months to date: PostgreSQL vs. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, date, time

PostgreSQL and Oracle behaviour in adding/subtracting months to/from date differs.

Basically, if we add 1 month to some day, which is **not the last one** of the month, they'll both return the same day number in the resulting month (or the last one for the resulting month if the day number we are adding to is greater, e.g. 28th of February when adding to 31th of January).

PostgreSQL:

```
# select '2015-01-12'::timestamptz + '1 month'::interval;
        date        
------------------------
 2015-02-12 00:00:00+03
```

Oracle:

```
> select add_months('12-JAN-2015',1) from dual;    
ADD_MONTH
---------
12-FEB-15
```

However.

If the day we are adding to is the last day of the month, Oracle will return the last day of the resulting month, even if it's bigger, and PostgreSQL will still return the same day number (or the lower one if the resulting month is shorter). This can lead to some inconsistency (even funny!), especially with adding/subtracting multiple times and even when grouping operations - in PostgreSQL the result differs:

Oracle:

```
> select add_months('28-FEB-2015',1) from dual;
ADD_MONTH
---------
31-MAR-15

> select add_months('31-JAN-2015',4) from dual;

ADD_MONTH
---------
31-MAY-15

> select add_months(add_months(add_months(add_months('31-JAN-2015',1),1),1),1) from dual;

ADD_MONTH
---------
31-MAY-15
```

PostgreSQL:

```
-- Adding 4 months at once:
# select '2015-01-31'::timestamptz + '4
months'::interval;
         date
-------------------------------
2015-05-31 00:00:00+03

-- Adding 4 months by one:
# select '2015-01-31'::timestamptz + '1
months'::interval + '1 months'::interval + '1 months'::interval +'1
months'::interval;
         date
-------------------------------
2015-05-28 00:00:00+03

-- Adding 4 months by one with grouping operations:
# select '2015-01-31'::timestamptz + ('1
months'::interval + '1 months'::interval) + '1 months'::interval +'1
months'::interval;
         date
-------------------------------
2015-05-30 00:00:00+03

-- And even adding 4 months and then subtracting them does not return the initial date!
# select '2015-01-31'::timestamptz + '1 months'::interval + '1 
months'::interval + '1 months'::interval +'1 months'::interval - '4 months'::interval;
        date        
------------------------
 2015-01-28 00:00:00+03
```

I know I could always use something like

```
SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', now())+'1 month'::interval - '1 day'::interval);
```

to get the last day of month and use it when adding months in PostgreSQL, but

the question is: why both of them chose to implement different standards, which one is better/worse and why.

Comment: I don't believe that date addition is part of the standard, so each product can implement it in whatever manner that the development team chooses. (And even if it *is* in the standard they can still implement it as they choose - they just won't be conformant :-). "Proper behavior" in cases such as this is more a matter of opinion than fact.

Comment: even in oracle you can use `date + interval`. It behaves according to ISO SQL Standard. add_months is Oracle proprietary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle specify that

> If date is the last day of the month or if the resulting month has
>   fewer days than the day component of date, then the result is the last
>   day of the resulting month. Otherwise, the result has the same day
>   component as date.

PostgreSQL specify that

> Note there can be ambiguity in the months returned by age because
>   different months have a different number of days. PostgreSQL's
>   approach uses the month from the earlier of the two dates when
>   calculating partial months. For example, age('2004-06-01',
>   '2004-04-30') uses April to yield 1 mon 1 day, while using May would
>   yield 1 mon 2 days because May has 31 days, while April has only 30.

You might want to have a look at the `justify_days(interval)` function provided by PostgreSQL.

> why both of them chose to implement different standards, which one is
>   better/worse and why ?

None of them is better then the other (it is mostly opinion based), simply different. As of why they decided to implement different standards, honestly I don't think there really is a reason, probably just a matter of facts.

Comment: Maybe they both had some arguments to choose one method over another. What bothers me is that in PostgreSQL it is not really an addition, because it's not associative :)

Comment: @Snifff I agree. However, I don't think there *arguments* are documented anywhere ;). Thats what I meant by "matter of facts".

Comment: I made the same conclusion, however I still hope someone knows more about these implementations :)

Comment: Even if I doubt it, I'd be happy to read it :).. Let's wait and see.

Comment: Seems like we will never get any explanation for that.

Comment: I guess we can say it's a matter of taste an purpose, so I think I'll just accept you answer, thanks!

Comment: @Snifff That's also what I think.. You're welcome :).